# Problem with scaling two different y-axis on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, yaxis

I want to plot a dataset on one x-axis and two y-axes (`eV` and `nm`). The two y-axis are linked together with the equation: `nm = 1239.8/eV`.

As you can see from my picture output, the values are not in the correct positions. For instance,  at `eV = 0.5` I need to have `nm = 2479.6`, at `eV = 2.9`, `nm = 423`, etc…

How can I fix this?

My `data.txt`:

```
number eV nm
1 2.573 481.9
2 2.925 423.9
3 3.174 390.7
4 3.242 382.4
5 3.387 366.1
```

The code I am using:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as tck

# data handling

file = "data.txt"

df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=" ")  # generate a DataFrame with data

no = df[df.columns[0]]
eV = df[df.columns[1]].round(2)  # first y-axis
nm = df[df.columns[2]].round(1)  # second y-axis

# generate a subplot 1x1

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

# first Axes object, main plot (lollipop plot)

ax1.stem(no, eV, markerfmt=' ', basefmt=" ", linefmt='blue', label="Gas")

ax1.set_ylim(0.5,4) 
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax1.set_xlabel('Aggregation', labelpad=12)
ax1.set_ylabel('Transition energy [eV]', labelpad=12)

# adding second y-axis

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(2680,350)  # set the corresponding ymax and ymin, 
                        # but the values are not correct anyway
ax2.set_yticklabels(nm)
ax2.set_ylabel('Wavelength [nm]', labelpad=12)

# save

plt.tight_layout(pad=1.5)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is the following. I just would like to obtain a second axis by dividing the first one by 1239.8, and I don't know what else to look for!

[image: attempted plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this problem ([source of the hint here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/m8fmxx/how_to_plot_a_two_yaxes_plot_with_matplotlib/)).

So, for anyone who needs to have one dataset with **one x-axis but two y-axes** (one mathematically related to the other), a working solution is reported. Basically, the problem is to have the same ticks as the main y-axis, but change them proportionally, according to their mathematical relationship (that is, in this case, `nm = 1239.8/eV`). The following code has been tested and it is working.

This method of course works if you have two x-axes and 1 shared y-axis, etc.

**Important note:** you must define an y-range (or x-range if you want the opposite result), otherwise you might get some scaling problems.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as tck
from matplotlib.text import Text

# data

file = "data.txt"

df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=" ")  # generate a DataFrame with data

no = df[df.columns[0]]
eV = df[df.columns[1]].round(2)  # first y-axis
nm = df[df.columns[2]].round(1)  # second y-axis

# generate a subplot 1x1

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

# first Axes object, main plot (lollipop plot)

ax1.stem(no, eV, markerfmt=' ', basefmt=" ", linefmt='blue', label="Gas")

ax1.set_ylim(0.5,4) 
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax1.set_xlabel('Aggregation', labelpad=12)
ax1.set_ylabel('Transition energy [eV]', labelpad=12)

# function that correlates the two y-axes

def eV_to_nm(eV):
    return 1239.8 / eV

# adding a second y-axis

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # share x axis
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())  # set the same range over y
ax2.set_yticks(ax1.get_yticks())  # put the same ticks as ax1
ax2.set_ylabel('Wavelength [nm]', labelpad=12)

# change the labels of the second axis by apply the mathematical 
# function that relates the two axis to each tick of the first
# axis, and then convert it to text
# This way you have the same axis as y1 but with the same ticks scaled

ax2.set_yticklabels([Text(0, yval, f'{eV_to_nm(yval):.1f}') 
                     for yval in ax1.get_yticks()])

# show the plot

plt.tight_layout(pad=1.5)
plt.show()
```

`data.txt` is the same as above:

```
number eV nm
1 2.573 481.9
2 2.925 423.9
3 3.174 390.7
4 3.242 382.4
5 3.387 366.1
```

[Output image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzDjV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ax.secondary_yaxis`, as described in [this example.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html) See the below code for an implementation for your problem. I have only included the part of the code relevant for the second y axis.

```
# adding second y-axis
def eV_to_nm(eV):
    return 1239.8 / eV

def nm_to_eV(nm):
    return 1239.8 / nm

ax2 = ax1.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(eV_to_nm, nm_to_eV))
ax2.set_yticks(nm)
ax2.set_ylabel('Wavelength [nm]', labelpad=12)
```

Note that I am also using `set_yticks` instead of `set_yticklabels`. Furthermore, if you remove `set_yticks`, matplotlib will automatically determine y tick positions assuming a linear distribution of y ticks. However, because `nm` is inversely proportional to `eV`, this will lead to a (most likely) undesirable distribution of y ticks. You can manually change these using a different set of values in `set_yticks`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately the [output plot](https://i.imgur.com/oEnCpUu.png) is even more messed up. Also, the second function should be `return 1239.8 * nm`

Comment: No, `1239.8 / nm` is correct. You can very simply verify this because the y ticks on the second axis match the heights of the drawn bars, which should be the case as you are setting the y ticks to the `nm` value corresponding to the plotted `eV` value, [see the plot.](https://i.imgur.com/mM7Snq8.png) Indeed, the y ticks are not at an optimal position, but this is something I already discussed in my answer.